# Where does apt-get or aptitude update download package lists to?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, command-line-interface, apt

I am having trouble with `aptitude update` and `apt-get update` not downloading a certain list file (specifically http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources [5,019 kB]).

I can download it through my browser from here: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources.bz2

Plan was to download through my local machine, FTP it to the server where `aptitude` and `apt-get` look for it and have it just `Hit` the file locally rather than re-download.

So I am looking for where `apt` downloads the source lists to, the package cache is of course `/var/cache/apt` but the package lists aren't there?

Comment: Is this what you are wanting?

***/var/lib/apt/lists/*** : storage area for state information for each package resource specified in sources.list From: http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***/var/lib/apt/lists/*** : Storage area for state information for each package resource specified in sources.list

From: *[man apt-get](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)*

Comment: Is the whole list always downloaded, or is it downloaded by some diff algorithm?